# Objects Values to be updated with Arrays Values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object 'graphData' and an array individualData.

I want the 'isPrimary: true' positionTitle from each user in my Array,
to replace all of the positionTitles for that same user in my object.
(some users have more than one positionTitle)

If there is no true isPrimary position then I want to take the first position for that user in the array and enter that into all of the positions in the graphData object.

My current code doesn't do that fully.

My Object:

```
graphData = {

"name": "Annual meetings",
"engagementAreas": [{
        "id": "1",
        "engagementTypes": [{
                "name": "forestry",
                "engagements": []
            },
            {
                "name": "houses",
                "engagements": [{
                    "name": "engagement1",
                    "members": [{
                        "id": "e334",
                        "account": {
                            "id": "123",
                            "fullName": "jim bean"
                        },
                        "position": {
                            "id": "3434",
                            "positionTitle": "Manager",
                            "isPrimary": false
                        }
                    }]
                }]
            },
            {
                "name": "landscaping",
                "engagements": [{
                    "name": "engagement1343",
                    "members": [{
                            "id": "e334",
                            "account": {
                                "id": "123",
                                "fullName": "john boer"
                            },
                            "position": {
                                "id": "4545",
                                "positionTitle": "Managing Director",
                                "isPrimary": true

                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "5555",
                            "account": {
                                "id": "123",
                                "fullName": "jim bean"
                            },
                            "position": {
                                "id": "a16b0000004AxeBAAS",
                                "positionTitle": "Managing Director",
                                "isPrimary": true

                            }

                        }


                    ]
                }]
            }
        ]
    },

    {
        "name": "community days",
        "engagementTypes": [{
                "name": "skyscraping",
                "engagements": []
            },
            {
                "name": "tennis",
                "engagements": [{
                    "name": "engagement346",
                    "members": [{
                        "id": "34",
                        "account": {
                            "id": "0010X000048DDMsQAO",
                            "fullName": "edy long"
                        },
                        "position": {
                            "id": "3999434",
                            "positionTitle": "Managing Director",
                            "isPrimary": true
                        }
                    }]
                }]
            },
            {
                "name": "Juicing",
                "engagements": [{
                    "name": "347343",
                    "members": [{
                        "id": "4546",
                        "account": {
                            "id": "001b000003WnPy1AAF",
                            "fullName": "jeff bint"
                        },
                        "position": {
                            "id": "35006",
                            "positionTitle": "Senior Manager, Energy"

                        }
                    }]
                }]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

My Array individualData:

```
IndividualData = [{

"account": {
    "id": "001b000003WnPy1AAF",
    "fullName": "jim bean"
  },
  "positions": [{
    "id": "123",
    "organizationId": "001b0000005gxmlAAA",
    "organizationName": "a",
    "positionTitle": "Dalius Senior Manager, Energy",
    "positionLevel": "5-Middle Management & Advisers",
    "isPrimary": true,
    "startDate": "2016-10-07",
    "endDate": null
  }]
},
{
    "account": {
        "id": "001b000003WnPy1AAF",
        "fullName": "jim bean"
      },
      "positions": [{
        "id": "a16b0000004AxeBAAS",
        "organizationId": "001b0000005gxmlAAA",
        "organizationName": "a",
        "positionTitle": "Senior Manager, Energy",
        "positionLevel": "5-Middle Management & Advisers",
        "isPrimary": false,
        "startDate": "2016-10-07",
        "endDate": null
      }]
    },
    {
  "account": {
    "id": "001b000003WnPy1AAF",
    "fullName": "jeff bint"
  },
  "positions": [{
    "id": "a16b0000004AxeBAAS",
    "organizationId": "001b0000005gxmlAAA",
    "organizationName": "a",
    "positionTitle": "Senior Manager, Energy",
    "positionLevel": "5-Middle Management & Advisers",
    "isPrimary": true,
    "startDate": "2016-10-07",
    "endDate": null
  }]
}, {
  "account": {
    "id": "0010X000048DDMsQAO",
    "fullName": "edy long"
  },
  "positions": [{
    "id": "a160X000004nKfhQAE",
    "organizationId": "001b0000005gxmlAAA",
    "organizationName": "a",
    "positionTitle": "Managing Director",
    "positionLevel": "4-Head of Business Unit/Head of Region",
    "isPrimary": true,
    "startDate": "2018-03-05",
    "endDate": null
  }]
},  {
    "account": {
      "id": "123",
      "fullName": "john boer"
    },
    "positions": [{
      "id": "325345634634",
      "organizationId": "001b0000005gxmlAAA",
      "organizationName": "a",
      "positionTitle": "Managing Director",
      "positionLevel": "4-Head of Business Unit/Head of Region",
      "isPrimary": true,
      "startDate": "2018-03-05",
      "endDate": null
    }]
  }

]
```

My current code:

```
const accountIdToPositionDict = IndividualData.reduce( (current, item) => {
    current[item.account.id] = (item.positions.filter( position => position.isPrimary )[0] || {} ).positionTitle;
    return current;
  }, {} );

  const updatedGraphTable = { ...graphData,
    engagementAreas: graphData.engagementAreas.map(area => ({ ...area,
      engagementTypes: area.engagementTypes.map(type => ({ ...type,
          engagements: type.engagements.map(engagement => ({ ...engagement,
            members: engagement.members.map(member => ({ ...member,
              position: { ...member.position,
                // use the found positionTitle, or the original one that was given
                positionTitle: member.account &&  accountIdToPositionDict[member.account.id] || member.position.positionTitle
              }
            }))
          }))}))
      }))
    };
```

My current output:

```
{
"name": "Annual meetings",
"engagementAreas": [{
    "id": "1",
    "engagementTypes": [{
        "name": "forestry",
        "engagements": []
    }, {
        "name": "houses",
        "engagements": [{
            "name": "engagement1",
            "members": [{
                "id": "e334",
                "account": {
                    "id": "a16b0000004AxeBAAS",
                    "fullName": "jim bean"
                },
                "position": {
                    "id": "3434",
                    "positionTitle": "Manager",
                    "isPrimary": false
                }
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "landscaping",
        "engagements": [{
            "name": "engagement1343",
            "members": [{
                "id": "e334",
                "account": {
                    "id": "123",
                    "fullName": "john boer"
                },
                "position": {
                    "id": "4545",
                    "positionTitle": "Managing Director",
                    "isPrimary": true
                }
            }, {
                "id": "5555",
                "account": {
                    "id": "123",
                    "fullName": "jim bean"
                },
                "position": {
                    "id": "a16b0000004AxeBAAS",
                    "positionTitle": "Managing Director",
                    "isPrimary": true
                }
            }]
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "name": "community days",
    "engagementTypes": [{
        "name": "skyscraping",
        "engagements": []
    }, {
        "name": "tennis",
        "engagements": [{
            "name": "engagement346",
            "members": [{
                "id": "34",
                "account": {
                    "id": "0010X000048DDMsQAO",
                    "fullName": "edy long"
                },
                "position": {
                    "id": "3999434",
                    "positionTitle": "Managing Director",
                    "isPrimary": true
                }
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "Juicing",
        "engagements": [{
            "name": "347343",
            "members": [{
                "id": "4546",
                "account": {
                    "id": "001b000003WnPy1AAF",
                    "fullName": "jeff bint"
                },
                "position": {
                    "id": "35006",
                    "positionTitle": "Senior Manager, Energy"
                }
            }]
        }]
    }]
}]
```

}

My current output:

```
{
"name": "Annual meetings",
"engagementAreas": [{
    "id": "1",
    "engagementTypes": [{
        "name": "forestry",
        "engagements": []
    }, {
        "name": "houses",
        "engagements": [{
            "name": "engagement1",
            "members": [{
                "id": "e334",
                "account": {
                    "id": "a16b0000004AxeBAAS",
                    "fullName": "jim bean"
                },
                "position": {
                    "id": "3434",
                    "positionTitle": "Dalius Senior Manager, Energy",
                    "isPrimary": false
                }
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "landscaping",
        "engagements": [{
            "name": "engagement1343",
            "members": [{
                "id": "e334",
                "account": {
                    "id": "123",
                    "fullName": "john boer"
                },
                "position": {
                    "id": "4545",
                    "positionTitle": "Managing Director",
                    "isPrimary": true
                }
            }, {
                "id": "5555",
                "account": {
                    "id": "123",
                    "fullName": "jim bean"
                },
                "position": {
                    "id": "a16b0000004AxeBAAS",
                    "positionTitle": "Dalius Senior Manager, Energy",
                    "isPrimary": true
                }
            }]
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "name": "community days",
    "engagementTypes": [{
        "name": "skyscraping",
        "engagements": []
    }, {
        "name": "tennis",
        "engagements": [{
            "name": "engagement346",
            "members": [{
                "id": "34",
                "account": {
                    "id": "0010X000048DDMsQAO",
                    "fullName": "edy long"
                },
                "position": {
                    "id": "3999434",
                    "positionTitle": "Managing Director",
                    "isPrimary": true
                }
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "Juicing",
        "engagements": [{
            "name": "347343",
            "members": [{
                "id": "4546",
                "account": {
                    "id": "001b000003WnPy1AAF",
                    "fullName": "jeff bint"
                },
                "position": {
                    "id": "35006",
                    "positionTitle": "Senior Manager, Energy"
                }
            }]
        }]
    }]
}]
```

}

As you can see the primary position for jim bean in my array data 
wasnt used to replace the objects data as desired.

Comment: I do not get the same output as you
{ '123': 'Managing Director',
  '001b000003WnPy1AAF': 'Senior Manager, Energy',
  '0010X000048DDMsQAO': 'Managing Director' }
{ name: 'Annual meetings',
  engagementAreas: 
   [ { id: '1', engagementTypes: [Array] },
     { name: 'community days', engagementTypes: [Array] } ] }

Comment: Your `IndividualData` seems to be messed up, as an account can have more than one position (it is an array in the end), but instead, the full account is replicated with each time a single position. Other than that, it now (vs your previous questions on the topic) seems that `isPrimary` is a part of your `graphData` where as before, it was not. You seem to have serious redundancy problems in how you fetch your data, and want to solve it by updating small logic steps. I think you should maybe check how you can generate the correct data in one set (ie, you are asking the wrong questions...)

Comment: Yes in the IndividualData array the accounts can have multiple positions, the data is less similar in the real data but I did this to be as minimalist as possible to get something on here.Yes I forgot to include isPrimary before, your right it's difficult but i'm calling on endpoints, the array is the new endpoint and that contains the primary positions that should now be included in the graph object

Comment: I manually added the almost duplicate entries into the array and only changed their positionID as thats all i thought that would matter

Comment: the entries only share the same name in the real data